# Are there memory limitations when outputting to a ScrolledText widget?

Tags: memory, logging, textbox, tkinter, python-3.4

I am fairly new to Python and to GUI programming, and have been learning the Tkinter package to further my development.

I have written a simple data logger that sends a command to a device via a serial or TCP connection, and then reads the response back, displaying it in a ScrolledText widget. In addition, I have a button that allows me to save the contents of the ScrolledText widget into a text file.

I was testing my software by sending a looped command, with a 0.5 second delay between commands. The aim was to test the durability of the logger so it may later be deployed to automatically monitor and log the output of the devices it is connected to.

After 30-40 minutes, I find that the program crashes on my Windows 7 system, and I suspect that it may be caused by a memory issue. The crash is a rather nondescript, "pythonw.exe has stopped working" message. When I monitor the process using Windows Task Manager, the memory used by pythonw.exe increases each time a response is read, and will eventually reach nearly 2Gb.

It may be that I need to rethink my logic and have the software log to the disk in 'real time', while the ScrolledText box overwrites the oldest data after x-number of lines... However, for my own education, I was wondering if there was a better way to manage the memory used by ScrolledText?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, there are no memory limitations with writing to a scrolled text widget. Internally, the text is stored in an efficient b-tree (efficient, unless all the data is a single line, since the b-tree leaves are lines). There might be a limit of some sort, but it would likely be in the millions of lines or so.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley, this would seem to suggest it is a design issue with my software then, rather than a limitation on the widget.